# Как параллельно запустить два setInterval в js

Tags: javascript

Добрый день.

Пишу браузерную игру на чистом js, метод отрисовки всей игры выполняется в setInterval(method, 10)

после того, как я добавил анимацию (смена кадров, скажем так), я добавил ее в тот же метод, который вызывается в setInterval.

В результате анимация отображается тоже с задержкой 10, хотя, самый оптимальный вариант, это установить для нее задержку в 60: setInterval(anim, 60).

Как вызвать два метода setInterval, чтобы первый занимался отрисовкой всей игры с задержкой 10, а второй занимался отрисовкой анимации с задержкой 60?

Comment: так и вызывай **два** метода. Просто второй не забудь остановить, когда он станет не нужен

Comment: вопервых `setInterval` поменяйте на `requestAnimationFrame` - а `FPS` не должен быть разным для отрисовки всей сцены и анимации - не надо такие костыли делать, уточните вопрос

Comment: Мне кажется в js не предусмотрена двупоточность. Прийдётся разпаралеливать "вручную". Если задача такая уж сложная используйте Flash - у него возможностей больше.

Comment: Отвечу каждому по-порядку: setInterval останавливать не нужно, т.к. он запускает метод отрисовки и всей логики игры. Если анимацию запускать в этом методе, то она будет воспроизводиться очень быстро.  Мне нужно просто чтобы одно рисовалось быстрее, а другое - медленнее. Flash использовать не стану, т.к. игра была задумана целиком и полностью на js, другие технологии для нее не рассматриваю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще для отрисовки текущих изменений самый оптимальный вариант использовать метод requestAnimationFrame: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame

Пример использования:

```
(function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(()=>{
        render();
        method();
    });
})();
```

Он будет выдавать 60 вызовов method в секунду или меньше, если компьютер не справляется с текущими задачами.
Кроме того нет никакого смысла в расчете промежуточных данных (анимации или модели игры) с задержкой в 10мс или менее, так как это создаст лишнюю нагрузку на процессор.

Кроме того, метод setInterval никогда не дает "честные" 10мс или любое другое переданное в него время. Сначала будут выполнены все вычисления и только после этого запущен обратный таймер. Также, если в Chrome переключиться на другую вкладку то задержка на скрытой вкладке искусственно увеличивается, чтобы уменьшить лишнюю нагрузку. Так что в любом случае, игровая модель должна получать текущее актуальное время, например Date.now();